# Renaming Distro Rout Folders & MinGW Setup Error

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I've just began in C++ using MinGW, but I am getting a basic error that I can't find a solution to on any forum. After installing MinGW to my folder "Club -Autnomous Rotics" (will correct the misspelling later after this problem is solved) and set my distro path to the same folder, I set up an independent folder for holding files, but I am unable to access commands to run my coding files.

I've had a friend who programs for a living kindly guide me through the installation and startup of this process, but this error was unsolvable by either of us. Any advice?

Screenshot attached: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssdj.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScDao.jpg

Comment: Please add the text of the message and not screenshots, as they will go out of date quickly.

Comment: WIll do, I used imgur since they don't expire all that fast.

Comment: The specific line of code I'm having trouble with is C:\College\Club - Autnomous Robotics\Coding Files\cpp Hello_World.c -o hwo.exe

Comment: Still not seeing the errors added to the question - if you don't do that, the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: When input, it gives a "compilation terminated" response

Comment: That's fine, thank you for the help though, I'll talk to my friend soon so hopefully we can resolve this issue then.